# Create named Mutex-Semaphore in Java

Tags: java, inno-setup

I would like to create mutex-semaphore for using with Inno Setup [`AppMutex` directive](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmutex). However I could not found named mutex in Java. All named mutex examples use data structure for storing name on classes and these are not fit my problem.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JNI to call the [`CreateMutex`  function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw) from WinAPI.

```
CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, mutexName);
```

Comment: To achieve the same on Linux there is `sem_open()`. Also, this is archived on github, but I think it works: https://github.com/hcoona/native-named-mutex